# 06215 sap error bapi_po_create1 net price as '0.14'?

Tags: abap, bapi

In bapi_po_create1 I can not send net price as 0.14. when it is greater than 1(for instance 14.98) it returns sales order number back.

Comment: It would be useful if you could include more detail on the issue (an example of the code you are trying to use, details of what document data you are trying to post etc)

Comment: when i try to do it with me21n it creates sales order. i didn't share any code because it returns sales order for money thats bigger than 1 also i checked the user exit and didn't see any control for money thats less than 1

Answer (score 0):

http://scn.sap.com/thread/1462485

here is the answer, found it.

Thanks